# I'm confused about compatibility of motherboard with AMD Ryzen 5950X

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, amd-ryzen

on Asus site, I read the M version of the mainboard supports Ryzen 5000:
https://www.asus.com/us/Product-Compare/?products=5wigvxws4h5eldnm,wcvny6reiwuvlf5u&b=0
while the other supports only Ryzen 3rd generation.

On tweakers, its the other way around:
https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/compare/1564258;1629530/
here, the **not**-M version mentions: AMD Ryzen™ 5000 Series/ 3000 Series Desktop Processors
while the M version just states: 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™ Processors

I think I read somewhere that **all** B550 ASUS boards are compatible with Ryzen 5000, perhaps after BIOS update. Or was it that all are compatible with 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™ Processors (but not necessarily the 5000 series)?

If you look here and then check the supported processors, **both** boards seem to support the 5000:
https://pangoly.com/en/compare/motherboard/b0a9ff51-b5b7-ea11-a95c-000d3a0da064,fb824d87-2237-eb11-8290-12c3a5b6f281

So, three sources, three different answers. Which source is right?
BTW, this site also summarizes the differences at the bottom, very handy.

I like the military grade components, like Japanese capacitors, on these boards.
But which one(s) is/are compatible with Ryzen 5950X?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you believe that Ryzen 5000 isn't 3rd generation?

Comment: Sources like this state the 3000 series is 3rd gen.
https://www.techradar.com/news/amd-ryzen-3rd-generation
https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=qa3&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk02BvQPmuT4gRdyeE10iOIemeIqQUw%3A1608555311984&ei=L5vgX_3RO4L3sAfl3L3IAg&q=3rd+generation+ryzen&oq=3rd+generation+ryzen&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1DREVjREWDiE2gAcAN4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi9peO_j9_tAhWCO-wKHWVuDykQ4dUDCAw&uact=5

Comment: Find a source that says the 5000 isn't.  Don't you think it would have hit the news if a 4th or 5th generation was available?

Comment: No need, see my answer to my own question below. But thanks anyways.

Comment: BTW, those Ryzen 3000 are Zen 2, while the Ryzen 5000 series is Zen 3, so they could have called this a new generation...

Comment: Not really, it's still 7 Nm TSMC mosfet.

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions here
https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1035322/

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/TUF-GAMING-B550-PLUS-WI-FI/HelpDesk_CPU/

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/TUF-GAMING-B550M-PLUS-WI-FI/HelpDesk_CPU

A cheaper board, still compatible with Noctua NH-D15 SE-AM4 cooler is PRIME B550M-A (WI-FI), but it does not have the military grade components.

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/PRIME-B550M-A-WI-FI/HelpDesk_CPU

So yes, all these are compatible with 5000 series, maybe you need to flash the BIOS if version is less than 1004 for Ryzen 9 5950X (Vermeer) (3.4GHz,105W,L3:64M,16C). Asus made flashing as painless as possible, you can do so without CPU or memory in the system!

For the cooler, you can check compatibility with the main board here:
https://ncc.noctua.at/motherboards

and with the casing here:
https://ncc.noctua.at/cases

I will use a low budget https://www.fractal-design.com/products/cases/focus/focus-g/black/
available in black, white, grey, red and blue.

With 64 GB RAM (Patriot 64G PVB464G360C8K Viper Blackout) and 2GB SDD (Sabrent) and 2GB HDD (Seagate Baracuda) I have a system (without monitor) for under 2000 euros. Who needs an 5990X with expensive mainboard, if I can buy 2 or 3 of these?

Edit: this budget of 2000 euros includes nice case coolers from Arctic, with ball bearings. Without chipset fan on the B550, it should be very quiet.

Comment: Apart from an old flemish saying "goedkoop is duurkoop".  ;-)

Comment: It's not just Flemish, but Dutch also. I don't save on the CPU cooler. Also the case fans are amongst the best. My main board (Asus) has military grade components, like Japanese capacitors. And there are Japanese capacitors in my power supply also. So I think I made sensible trade offs. The case may be low budget, but allows you to have 2 fans of 140 mm at the front, two fans of 140 mm at the top, at least one 120 mm, possibly also 140 mm at the bottom if you don't need the SSD bay, and one 120 mm at the back. Of course, for 50 euros you don't get the best quality, but cooling is not an issue.